# kdl or orocos_kdl from electric to indigo

Tags: ros, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there, i'm new to ros. my friend has ros files with ros-electric structure and now i want to use it with indigo..

and now i have problem with `kdl` or `orocos_kdl` (everytime i search about `kdl` on google, it always shown `orocos-kdl`, so i thought today they called it `orocos_kdl`. am i wrong?).

after i following ros-tutorial rosbuild to catkin, i try to `catkin_make`, and this is the result

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "orocos_kdl" with
  any of the following names:

    orocos_kdlConfig.cmake
    orocos_kdl-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "orocos_kdl" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "orocos_kdl_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "orocos_kdl" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  skripsi_mocap/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/adelleodel/rosadel/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/adelleodel/rosadel/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

anyway, the `orocos_kdl` was write down for `kdl` before. because i thought it's a call-name failure so i changed it to `orocos_kdl` on `CMakeList` and `package.xml`. so i don't know if my decision is right enough or not.

i'm following this link: [linking-against-kdl-ros-hydro](http://www.orocos.org/forum/orocos/orocos-users/linking-against-kdl-ros-hydro).

and this is my CMakeList :
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
...
orocos_kdl
..
)

```
....

find_library(orocos_kdl_LIBRARY NAMES ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES} PATHS
${orocos_kdl_LIBRARY_DIRS} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
set(orocos_kdl_LIBRARIES ${orocos_kdl_LIBRARY})

....

catkin_package(DEPENDS orocos_kdl)
```

please help me.. :"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220038/kdl-or-orocos_kdl-from-electric-to-indigo/) by [adelleodel](https://answers.ros.org/users/24939/adelleodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-10-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since `orocos_kdl` is not a catkin package you need to find it separately and not as part of the `find_package(catkin)`

So try

```
find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)
```

instead of

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS orocos_kdl)
```

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) with karma: 543 on 2015-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4